# Taylor Expansion and Simple Inequality $\ln(1+x) \geq x - \frac{x^2}{2(1-|x|)}$.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, taylor-expansion

Why does Taylor's Expansion Theorem show that $$\ln(1+x) \geq x - \frac{x^2}{2(1-|x|)}$$ for all $-1 < x < 1$. So far I have that
\begin{align}
\ln(1+x) &= x - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3} - \frac{x^4}{4} \dots
\end{align} and for $x \geq 0$
\begin{align}
\ln(1+x) &= x - \frac{x^2}{2} + \epsilon
\end{align} where $\epsilon \geq 0,$ therefore for $0 \leq x < 1$
\begin{align}
\ln(1+x) &= x - \frac{x^2}{2} + \epsilon\\
&\geq x - \frac{x^2}{2} \\
&\geq x - \frac{x^2}{2(1-|x|)}
\end{align}
But I am also searching over $-1 < x < 0$ and don't understand why the equation still holds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}
\ln(1+x) &= x - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3} - \frac{x^4}{4} \dots\\
&= x-\dfrac{x^2}{2}\left(1 - \frac{2x}{3} + \frac{2x^2}{4} - \frac{2x^3}{5} \dots\right)\\
&\geqslant x-\dfrac{x^2}{2}\left(1+|x|+|x|^2+ \dots\right)\\
&\geqslant   x - \frac{x^2}{2(1-|x|)}
\end{align}
for $|x|<1$.